# Android request API google via Wifi will be delay or timeout

Tags: android, google-api, wifi

I using google API for detecting Address from a location. I'm using Place API, Geocoding, Direction with Pro Google Api KEY. Here is my request's URL :
[Link API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=21.0272541,105.8338909&key=APIKEY)

When requesting by Retrofit via Wifi in Android device, response will be delay much time, otherwise, request perfectly with 3G/4G/LTE. Anyone can explain, please tell me a solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Post your code so that we could look into it

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue many times and ended up with the result i.e. **HTTPS Handshaking.** HTTPS requires an initial handshake which can be very slow. The actual amount of data transferred as part of the handshake isn't huge (under 5 kB typically), but for very small requests, this can be quite a bit of overhead. However, once the handshake is done, a very fast form of symmetric encryption is used, so the overhead there is minimal.

Bottom line: making lots of short requests over HTTPS will be quite a bit slower over different domains than HTTP, but if you transfer a lot of data in a single request, the difference will be insignificant.